# Xamarin's new way of performing OnPlatform StaticResource binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, static-binding

Previously I was able to do something like this

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
```

Now that, that syntax is deprecated, I'm trying to do this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
   <On Platform="Android">{StaticResource Primary}</On>
</OnPlatform>
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert "{StaticResource Primary}" into Xamarin.Forms.Color
```

How should my syntax be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `StaticResource` is a markup extension, you can use it either through [attribute usage, or element usage](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d108dfe17652d3f6a18bf76d0b7f955b74244998/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticResourceExtension.cs)

For example, try this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
</OnPlatform>
```

or,

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
    <On Platform="Android">
         <StaticResource Key="Primary" />
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```